# Operator overloading in Boo - op_NotEqual?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, boo

I have an old C# library that I am converting to Boo, and it uses operator overloading. In the interest of not to getting into the *why* of that, I am looking for a way do the same thing in Boo.

This takes the form:

```
public static bool operator <(Duration duration, TimeSpan timespan) {...}
```

But, Boo uses a different form of operator overloading, and does not have an 'operator' keyword.

```
public static def op_LessThan(duration as Duration, timespan as TimeSpan) as bool:
    pass
```

(From http://boo.codehaus.org/Operator+overloading)

These binary operators can be overloaded:

- op_Addition
- op_Subtraction
- op_Multiply
- op_Division
- op_Modulus
- op_Exponentiation
- op_Equality
- op_LessThan
- op_LessThanOrEqual
- op_GreaterThan
- op_GreaterThanOrEqual
- op_Match
- op_NotMatch
- op_Member
- op_NotMember
- op_BitwiseOr
- op_BitwiseAnd

But I don't see anything like op_NotEqual(!=) in that list. Are these methods equivalent to the above C# code? And if so, what would be the equivalent of

```
public static bool operator !=(Duration duration, TimeSpan timespan) {...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `op_Inequality` (from the C#/.NET side) - but I don't know if or how this is supported in Boo.  I suspect it's just a documentation error, and will likely work fine.